# Running Ubuntu 20.04 and can't extend displays with nvidia-driver-455

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, multiple-monitors

I changed my graphics driver to NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-445 (proprietary, tested) and everything is smooth but I can't extend my displays. To be specific my laptop does not detect any display to extend but when I unplug one of them, the monitor turns on for a bit then off, and vice versa. So the monitors know they're being connected but the laptop doesn't. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

````
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
1920x1080 144.00*+ 60.01 59.97 59.96 60.00 59.93
1680x1050 84.94 74.89 69.88 59.95 59.88
1600x1024 60.17
1400x1050 85.00 74.76 70.00 59.98
1600x900 59.99 59.94 59.95 59.82
1280x1024 85.02 75.02 60.02
1440x900 59.89
1400x900 59.96 59.88
1280x960 85.00 60.00
1440x810 60.00 59.97
1368x768 59.88 59.85
1360x768 59.80 59.96
1280x800 59.99 59.97 59.81 59.91
1152x864 100.00 85.06 85.00 75.00 75.00 70.00 60.00
1280x720 60.00 59.99 59.86 59.74
1024x768 85.00 75.05 60.04 85.00 75.03 70.07 60.00
1024x768i 86.96
960x720 85.00 75.00 60.00
928x696 75.00 60.05
896x672 75.05 60.01
1024x576 59.95 59.96 59.90 59.82
960x600 59.93 60.00
832x624 74.55
960x540 59.96 59.99 59.63 59.82
800x600 85.00 75.00 70.00 65.00 60.00 85.14 72.19 75.00 60.32 56.25
840x525 85.02 74.96 69.88 60.01 59.88
864x486 59.92 59.57
800x512 60.17
700x525 85.08 74.76 70.06 59.98
800x450 59.95 59.82
640x512 85.02 75.02 60.02
720x450 59.89
700x450 59.96 59.88
640x480 85.09 60.00 85.01 72.81 75.00 59.94
720x405 59.51 58.99
720x400 85.04
684x384 59.88 59.85
680x384 59.80 59.96
640x400 59.88 59.98 85.08
576x432 100.11 85.15 85.09 75.00 75.00 70.00 60.06
640x360 59.86 59.83 59.84 59.32
640x350 85.08
512x384 85.00 75.03 70.07 60.00
512x384i 87.06
512x288 60.00 59.92
416x312 74.66
480x270 59.63 59.82
400x300 85.27 72.19 75.12 60.32 56.34
432x243 59.92 59.57
320x240 85.18 72.81 75.00 60.05
360x202 59.51 59.13
360x200 85.04
320x200 85.27
320x180 59.84 59.32
320x175 85.27
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)```
````

Comment: Hi ! Some `inxi -SPARM -GCDN -v1 -xGCRS` would be appreciable so we'd know more about your system. All we know is that you have Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop, and that's all. Also, does the `nvidia-settings` also see no second monitor ?
Also, `apt list -i *xorg* *nvidia*` .